# Generate tr on click of Image button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario where I want to duplicate the existing `<tr>` whenever I click on  `+` button which is: `<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Below is my `<tr>`. how to generate this using jquery or javascript

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="row noPadding vendorForm">
            <div class="vendorDaterow">
                <div class="vendorName">
                    <label>SP Vender Name</label><span>Shri Kamalkanth Co.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="vendorFromDate">
                    <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spFromDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="vendorToDate">
                    <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spToDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="add">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <i class="max">(Maximum 5 Vendors)</i>

        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Satpal: no not to toggle, I want to add the same tr whenever user clicks on + button

Comment: You can use .append()

Comment: Then `$(existingSelectorForTr).clone(true, true).appendTo('table')`

Comment: @Satpal: Sorry didn't got you

Comment: and then you also need to attach the datepickers and change their IDs

Comment: @mplungjan: how to do that.. yes ID's will play an important role here. do let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```js
(function () {
  var toAddCloneCount = 2;

$('.add').on('click', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var $tr2 = $tr.clone(true, true);
  $tr2.find(".vendorName").children('label').remove();
  $tr2.find(".add").children().remove();
  $tr2.find(".vendorFromDate").children('label').remove();
  $tr2.find(".vendorToDate").children('label').remove();
  $tr2.find('#txtVendorName').prop('id', 'txtVendorName' + toAddCloneCount);
  $tr2.find('#spFromDate1').prop('id', 'spFromDate' + toAddCloneCount);
  $tr2.find('#spToDate1').prop('id', 'spToDate' + toAddCloneCount++);
  $tr2.insertAfter($tr);
});
})();
```

```css
.vendorName,.vendorFromDate,.vendorToDate{
width:33%;float:left;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row noPadding vendorForm">
                                    <div class="vendorDaterow">
                                        <div class="vendorName">
                                            <label>SP Vender Name</label><span>@*Shri Kamalkanth Co.*@<input type="text" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName" /></span> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vendorFromDate">
                                            <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spFromDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vendorToDate">
                                            <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spToDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <i class="max">(Maximum 5 Vendors)</i>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not getting you, td in tr which also will be added in snippet and I have changed in snippet now you can add only first tr.

Comment: Actually there is a slight change in my requirement. Will let u know in sometime

Comment: hi are u their now ? need to ask something related to this

Comment: hello @VVVV tell me your requirement

Comment: now I want to show only `<span>Shri Kamalkanth Co.</span> <span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spFromDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spToDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>` on + click

Comment: You have to change in your table format or you can use div format for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160615/discussion-between-gattbha-and-vvvv).

Comment: going home now will discuss tomorrow. sorry

Comment: hi are u their?  i am online on chat

Comment: hi, are u their ?? need one small help. please come on chat

Comment: Hello ,I am on the way so I am not in front of pc after an hour I will ping you

Comment: Sure i will ping

Comment: i will tell u what I want, I want to generate ID's for each textbox so that I can loop while saving the data

Comment: hi bro, are you their. If yes come on chat.

Answer (score 2):

You'd first **[clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)** the parent `<tr/>` by finding it through **[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** and insert it as a sibling via **[insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)**.  Make sure to also pass `true` as arguments so that all descendants are passed along with their events and data.

```
$('.add').on('click', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

  $tr.clone(true, true).insertAfter($tr)
});
```

Comment: its working but there is slight change in my requirement can u help ?

Comment: Sure what is it?

Comment: now I want to show only `<span>Shri Kamalkanth Co.</span>
<span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spFromDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spToDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>` on + click

Comment: its working but I dont want vendorName div and vendorForm div

Comment: Then you'd just simply remove those divs. I don't see how this would affect your current functionality.

Comment: remove div's from where. In your js you have not mentioned any div. so how can I remove that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160612/discussion-between-vvvv-and-carl-edwards).

Comment: My answer is only targeting the button and the tr tag. You can do whatever you want with everything else.

Comment: i tried adding <div> in place of tr but still it didnt worked

Comment: Whatever is your topmost parent container, give it a unique id and use that. closest() targets the closest parent. Since you have multiple divs it's stopping too early.

Answer (score 1):

Use `clone()` and `after()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("i.fa-plus").click(function(){
        var val = $("tr:last").clone()
        $("tr:last").after(val)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="row noPadding vendorForm">
            <div class="vendorDaterow">
                <div class="vendorName">
                    <label>SP Vender Name</label><span>Shri Kamalkanth Co.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="vendorFromDate">
                    <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spFromDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="vendorToDate">
                    <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="spToDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
 </table>
            <div class="add">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">+</i>
            </div>
            <i class="max">(Maximum 5 Vendors)</i>
```

Comment: And change id and attach datepicker

Comment: @mplungjan: can u help sir on binding it ?

Comment: @VVVV Do you need to change the id of inputs in each tr cloned? Like spFromDate2 etc?

Answer (score 0):

You need the template of the `<tr>` somehow. Use some kind of templating engine or the lazy way: copy it on page load. (to not have existing input when copying the `<tr>`)

```
var $template = $('yourTrSelector').clone();
```

And then paste it on button click.

```
$('yourButtonSelector').on('click', function(){
  $('yourTableSelector').append($template.copy());
});
```